# Getting and Setting an Enum in C#

Tags: c#, enums, get, set

When I try the code below, I get a message that "the name C does not exist in the current context." What am I missing here? I would like the position part in the dictionary to behave just like the other variables, but I've been having trouble using the enum. Thanks!

```
class stats
    {
        enum pos { fiB, seB, SS, thB, LF, CF, RF, C, DH, SP, RP };
        public double age {get; set;}
        public pos position{get; set;}
        public double ovalue{get; set;}
        public double dvalue{get; set;}
    }
    public partial class playerdictionary:stats
    {
        public playerdictionary()
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, stats>();
            dict.Add("AG", new stats { age = 24, position=C, ovalue = 0, dvalue = 4.2 });

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried `pos.C`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the enum's name `pos`.

```
position = pos.C;
//         ^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

It should read:

```
position = pos.C
```